# How do I use the default arg in json.dumps to delete a specific property?

Tags: python

I have a data structure like so:

```
{
    "name": "hello world",
    "parent": <ref to an object of the same structure>,
    "children": [objects of this same structure]
}
```

where parent is a circular reference, and each item in `children` also has a parent property and an either empty or populated `children` array, containing more of the shown object, each with a circular parent reference.

I want to export this structure to JSON (while leaving out the circular `parent` properties), with a method like so:

```
import json
import copy

class DataObject():
    def __init__(self, parent = False, name = ""):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.name = name

    def append(self, parent = False, name = ""):
        self.children.append(DataObject(parent = self, name = name))

    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: delattr(copy(o.__dict__), "parent"), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Obviously this isn't going to work because `delattr` doesn't return the updated object, so I need to delete the attribute from the copy on one line, then return the updated copy on the next line, but I'm new to Python and don't understand how to pass a multiline function as an argument when the language's function delimiters are tabs, not brackets.

Also totally possible that I'm not even on the right track. How can I remove the `parent` property from objects being JSON dumped recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work: for otherwise un-jsonable objects define an `json_repr` method, which removes the bits you don't want to represent in JSON, and then call that in `default`.

I've split out `as_json()` so you could call it with other objects than just `DataObject`s too.

```
import json


def as_json(obj):
    return json.dumps(
        obj,
        default=lambda o: o.json_repr(),
        sort_keys=True,
        indent=4,
    )


class DataObject:
    def __init__(self, parent=False, name=""):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.name = name

    def append(self, parent=False, name=""):
        self.children.append(DataObject(parent=self, name=name))

    def json_repr(self):
        d = vars(self).copy()
        d.pop("parent")
        return d

    def as_json(self):
        return as_json(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a multiline function as an argument, just define it locally and pass the name as argument. For example:

```
import json
from copy import copy

class DataObject():
    def __init__(self, parent = False, name = ""):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.name = name

    def append(self, parent = False, name = ""):
        self.children.append(DataObject(parent = self, name = name))

    def toJSON(self):
        def without_parent(x):
            items = copy(x.__dict__)
            del items["parent"]
            return items
        return json.dumps(self, default=without_parent, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

a = DataObject(name="A")
print(a.toJSON())

##Output: 
##  {
##     "children": [],
##     "name": "A"
##  }
```